# Function to create a square matrix with and assign values

Tags: matrix, function-construction, variable-definitions

I am trying to create a function that returns a matrix as in the description below.

The function has five inputs:

- M: name of the matrix
- n: size of the matrix nxn
- a, b, c: integer numbers with $0 \le  a,b, c\le n$

Next I will assign elements of the matrix with **both non-zero column and** **non-zero row indices** as below. All the remaining elements are assigned 0 values.

```
M[[a,a]] = x11;

M[[a,b]] = x12;

M[[a,c]] = x13;

M[[b,a]] = x21;

M[[b,b]] = x22;

M[[b,c]] = x23;

M[[c,a]] = x31;

M[[c,b]] = x32;

M[[c,c]] = x33;
```

How can I do this? I don't know how to give name M as an input to a function, and also this function is complex to me. I haven't written any function with more many code lines like this.

For now I am just starting something, but I am not sure if it is correct.

```
    myfunc[M_, n_, a_, b_, c_] := (M = Table[0, {n}, {n}];

        If[a > 0, M[[a,a]] = x11, M[[a,a]] = 0];
        If[a > 0 && b > 0, M[[a,b]] = x12, M[[a,b]] = 0];
        If[a > 0 && c > 0, M[[a,c]] = x13, M[[a,c]] = 0];
        If[b > 0, M[[b,b]] = x22, M[[b,b]] = 0];
        If[b > 0 && a > 0, M[[b,a]] = x21, M[[b,a]] = 0];
        If[b > 0 && c > 0, M[[b,c]] = x23, M[[b,c]] = 0];
        If[b > 0 && a > 0, M[[b,a]] = x21, M[[b,a]] = 0];
        If[b > 0, M[[b,b]] = x22, M[[b,b]] = 0];
        If[b > 0 && c > 0, M[[b,c]] = x23, M[[b,c]] = 0];
        If[c > 0 && a > 0, M[[c,a]]= x31, M[[c,a]] = 0];
        If[c > 0 && b > 0, M[[c,b]] = x32, M[[c,b]] = 0];
        If[c > 0, M[[c,c]] = x33, M[[c,c]] = 0];)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is another, (more flexible?) way:

```
f[n_Integer, list_?VectorQ, vals_?MatrixQ] := Module[{M, idx, idx1},
 idx = Pick[Range[Length[list]], UnitStep[list - 1] UnitStep[n - list], 1];
 M = ConstantArray[0, {n, n}];
 idx1 = list[[idx]];
 M[[idx1, idx1]] = vals[[idx, idx]];
 M
 ]

xx = Array[ToExpression[StringJoin["x", IntegerString[{##}]]] &, {3, 3}];
M = f[8, {1, 4, 7}, xx];
M//MatrixForm
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccccccc}
 \text{x11} & 0 & 0 & \text{x12} & 0 & 0 & \text{x13} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \text{x21} & 0 & 0 & \text{x22} & 0 & 0 & \text{x23} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \text{x31} & 0 & 0 & \text{x32} & 0 & 0 & \text{x33} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

Entries $i$ in `list` will now also be ignored if they do not fullfil $1 \leq i \leq n$.

Comment: Thanks, short and great too!

Comment: Hi,  when one input is zero, the code doesn't work. Assume that a = 0 but b, c are non-zero then elements with bc, cb also should be assigned as above. How can I fix that?

Comment: Mathematica's array are 1-based; index zero makes no sense. But you can enter, e.g., `f[8, {4,7}, xx]` if want to set only two colums and two rows. In fact, the second argument `list` can be any list of integers between `1` and `n` of length at most the length of the matrix `vals` (which is suppose to be a square matrix).

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood a bit. For example, f[4,0,2,3] then only the elements [[2,2]], [[2,3]]  [[3,2]], [[3,3]] are set to their x values.  
Like this: https://i.imgur.com/SUMOdiC.png

Comment: Ah, I think I got it. See my edit.

Comment: Yeah, it works well now. I will use this for my circuit analysis!

Comment: I'm glad to hear that! You're welcome!

Answer (score 6):

Here's one way:

```
myfunc[n_Integer?Positive, a_Integer?Positive, b_Integer?Positive, c_Integer?Positive] /;
  Max[a, b, c] <= n := 
  Normal[SparseArray[Thread[Tuples[{a, b, c}, {2}] ->
                            {x11, x12, x13, x21, x22, x23, x31, x32, x33}], {n, n}]]
```

Test:

```
myfunc[8, 1, 4, 7] // MatrixForm
```

$$\begin{pmatrix}
 \mathtt{x11} & 0 & 0 & \mathtt{x12} & 0 & 0 & \mathtt{x13} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \mathtt{x21} & 0 & 0 & \mathtt{x22} & 0 & 0 & \mathtt{x23} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \mathtt{x31} & 0 & 0 & \mathtt{x32} & 0 & 0 & \mathtt{x33} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

---

If you want to be able to use `0` as an indicator to ignore an entry:

```
myfunc[n_Integer?Positive, a_Integer?NonNegative,
       b_Integer?NonNegative, c_Integer?NonNegative] /; Max[a, b, c] <= n := 
  Normal[SparseArray[Select[Thread[
 Tuples[{a, b, c}, {2}] ->
 {x11, x12, x13, x21, x22, x23, x31, x32, x33}], FreeQ[First[#], 0] &], {n, n}]]
```

Test:

```
myfunc[8, 0, 4, 7] // MatrixForm
```

$$\begin{pmatrix}
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & \mathtt{x22} & 0 & 0 & \mathtt{x23} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & \mathtt{x32} & 0 & 0 & \mathtt{x33} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Here's a `SparseArray[]` equivalent of Henrik's routine:

```
myfuncgen[n_Integer?Positive, idx_List, ent_?SquareMatrixQ] /; 
  Length[idx] <= n && Length[idx] == Length[ent] && 
  VectorQ[idx, IntegerQ] && 0 <= Min[idx] && Max[idx] <= n := 
Normal[SparseArray[Select[Thread[Tuples[idx, {2}] -> Flatten[ent]], 
                          FreeQ[First[#], 0] &], {n, n}]]
```

Test:

```
myfuncgen[8, {1, 0, 7},
          Array[Symbol["x" <> IntegerString[#1] <> IntegerString[#2]] &, {3, 3}]]
```

$$\begin{pmatrix}
 \mathtt{x11} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \mathtt{x13} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \mathtt{x31} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \mathtt{x33} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. Look great but that beyond my current lever! I need to practice more! I wrote my code above. It is somewhat long and many errors.

Comment: Hi, I just checked that when one input is zero, the code doesn't work. Assume that a = 0 but b, c are non-zero then elements with bc, cb also should be assigned as above. How can I fix that?

Comment: For example, f[4,0,2,3] then only the elements [[2,2]], [[2,3]] [[3,2]], [[3,3]] are set to their x values. We only set elements with indices non-zero  Like this:https://i.imgur.com/SUMOdiC.png

Comment: @anhnha, check now

Comment: Yeah, it works well now. Thanks!